# yii how to combine CJuiAutoComplete option select with php variable

Tags: yii

How do I include a PHP variable in a CJuiAutoComplete jquery? My sample below was not successful. Sorry for my bad English.

```
<?php
    echo $count=$t['id'];
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete',
      array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'attribute'=>"jwtn".$t["id"],
        'sourceUrl'=>$this->createUrl('KemsainsCalon/lookup'),
        'htmlOptions'=>array('placeholder'=>$model->isNewRecord ? "Nama ahli" : "ok"),
        'options'=>
           array(
                 'showAnim'=>'fold',
                 'select'=>"js:function(parsoalan, ui) { 
                            // below is my problem, #KemsainsCalon_jwtn_id<?php echo $count?>, how do I concat php variables in jquery 
                            $('#KemsainsCalon_jwtn_id<?php echo $count?>').val(ui.item.id); 
                     }"
                ),
        'cssFile'=>'jquery-ui.css',
      )); 
    ?>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

You can handle `$count` like you would in a normal php string. `select` may be javascript code but it's still a php string for now.

```
...
'select'=>"js:function(parsoalan, ui) { 
    $('#KemsainsCalon_jwtn_id".$count."').val(ui.item.id); 
}"
```